# Convert date to "dd.MM.yyyy" format in Swift

Tags: swift, nsdateformatter

I work with an API where one of parameters is of type Date in the format "dd.MM.yyyy”.

I can't manage to convert it. I created an extension for Date where I tried to implement it this way:

```
extension Date {

  var shortDate: Date {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy"
    let strDate = formatter.string(from: self)
    let modifiedDate = formatter.date(from: strDate)
    return modifiedDate!
  }
}
```

and I call it like this:

```
let day = Date().shortDate
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work and it looks like this:

> 2017-06-18 21:00:00 +0000

How can I solve it?

Comment: That's correct. What result you expect?

Comment: @Sulthan I expect to get number in format 18.06.2017

Comment: You are returning a date. A date has no format and no timezone. Why don't you return `strDate` which probably contains the correct result?

Comment: What is the sense to convert date to string and back to date? `Date` is a wrapper of a `Double`, nothing else. Consider that a `Date` object is always `print`ed in `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z` format.

Comment: @Sulthan, thanks, to be honest I didnt know that

Comment: @vadian thanks for help, I didnt know that date is always in the same format

Comment: As Sulthan already mentioned, `Date` has no format at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understand, you need to communicate with an API which represents Date in the format `"dd.MM.yyyy”`. Here are the simple functions you'll need to implement:

```
class MyAPIFunctions
{
    static let formatter: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy"

        // make sure the following are the same as that used in the API
        formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
        formatter.locale = Locale.current

        return formatter
    }()

    class func shortString(fromDate date: Date) -> String {
        return formatter.string(from: date)
    }

    class func date(fromShortString string: String) -> Date? {
        return formatter.date(from: string)
    }
}
```

I have declared `formatter` as a separate constant to save the overhead of re-initialization with each call.
Once you have added these functions, you can send a date to the API as follows:

```
let today = Date()
let todayString = MyAPIFunctions.shortString(fromDate: today)
// send todayString to API
```

To convert a string in the API to a Date object,

```
let apiString = "17.07.2017"
guard let apiDate = MyAPIFunctions.date(fromShortString: apiString) else {
    // deal with formatting error here
    return
}
// work with apiDate object
```

Comment: Don't forget that you should always set locale when parsing/encoding API formats, otherwise you can get suprising results when a non-gregorian calendar is used by the current locale.

Answer (score 0):

```
 let date = Date.init()
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"

        formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US") as Locale!
        let strdate1 = formatter.string(from: date as Date)

        print(strdate1)
```

Comment: of course thanks for answer, but the question wasnt how to convert date to string. but how to convert date into date. that wasnt smart from my side .

Comment: Although this code might (or might not) answer the question, one should always explain what it does and how it solves the problem.